# Filtering locales out of production build at build time in android

Tags: android, internationalization, locale, android-build, build-settings

Is there a documented way by which one can filter out a supported locale while building an android app? For example, if I have a locale for which support is only partially built, I want to include it in a debug build but exclude it from my release build, is there a configuration setting I can mess with to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm tough one, you can query for the Locale and change it, if it is set to a Locale you don't like, something with using this api:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault(java.util.Locale)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault%28java.util.Locale%29)

Then if you want this in your development build and not in your live build you would need different configurations when you build your APK. This would involve using Ant.

To do this, you'll have to read up:

[Switching Android Configs using Constants and Ant](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/switching-android-configurations-using-constants-and-ant/)

Alternatively, you could use the above style of ant script configuration and override the locale folders with empty folders for your live build, that would be an interesting experiment.